# Exclude category from related post

Tags: categories, posts

I made a related post sidebar widget and im trying to exclude a category from it i tried 'exclude'=>7932 but that doesnt seem to work, is there another way to do this?

```
            <?php $category = get_the_category();
            $parent = get_cat_id($category[0]->category_parent);
            $parent = $category[0]->cat_id; ?>
            <ul class="recent-widget-container">
            <?php
            $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
            if ($categories) {
            $category_ids = array();
            foreach($categories as $individual_category) $category_ids[] = $individual_category->term_id;
            $args=array(
            'category__in' => $category_ids,
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
            'showposts'=>5, // Number of related posts that will be shown.
            'caller_get_posts'=>1,
            'exclude'=>7932,
            );

            $my_query = new wp_query($args);
            if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
            $my_query->the_post();
            ?>
            <?php $id = get_the_ID(); ?>

            <?php $image_meta = get_post_meta($id,'image',true); ?>

            <li class="recent-widget-post">
            <div class="recent-widget-img">
            <?php if ( (isset($image_meta)) && ($image_meta != '') ) { 
            woo_image('key=image&width=140&height=80');
            }else{  echo $small_placeholder;}   ?>
            </div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <p><?php get_the_excerpt_limit( 75, '...' ); ?></p>
            <div class="fix"></div>
            </li>            
            <?php
            }
            }
            }
            $post = $orig_post;
            wp_reset_query();
            ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `category__not_in => array(7932)` instead.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters